# How do I start the MySQL console in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, console

The XAMPP installation is done. XAMPP is up and running.

What about the MySQL console?
How is possible to start the MySQL console to run some special SQL statements?

Comment: Remember there are a lot better ways to deploy web server in Ubuntu than XAMPP. They're also easier and more reliable. Create a new question if you want to know the process.

Answer (score 32):

just start mysql using the command

example: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql`

and find path of mysql , it will be placed in bin directory of lampp, then login

example: `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root`

Comment: that is perfect ans for linux xampp

Answer (score 5):

From the terminal type `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE` which is:

`mysql` The actual command to use mysql

`-uUSER` is what user will connect. The **-u** is the parameter for the user and the USER part is the actual name of the user.

`-pPASSWORD` is the password for that user. the **-p** is the parameter for the password and the PASSWORD is the actual password.

the DATABASE part is optional. Is just if you want to connect directly to a particular database. For example, let us say the user cyrex with password ubuntu wants to connect to the database linux, you would type this:

`mysql -ucyrex -pubuntu linux` (User is cyrex, password is ubuntu and the database is linux)

if you do not add the database you can eventually go to it by using the **use** statement of mysql or searching for the database with **show databases;**

Comment: +1: This is the usual solution, but I'm afraid that XAMPP doesn't actually deploy mysql like this. I don't use XAMPP so I'm not sure, but my friend has it and I hate its every bit. If my assumptions are true, your solution might not work for the OP, but it's still correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're wondering about the package [Apache Friends Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html). The only way init is MySql

```
~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
```

If it's something

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Xampp's Control Panel has a shell button, click that and it may show a dialog box saying that the #bat file needs to be created, and if it should create it now.. You should say **Yes**.

After that, it will open a console window.
From that console window you can easily access mysql by typing the following.

`mysql -u mysqluser --p mysqlpass`

in my own personal installation i use the below (because i don't have a pass set for user @root).

`mysql -u root`

Btw, if it isn't obvious already I am using windows, so there could be some differences in the ubuntu version.

Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 1):

First use this command in shell (Ubuntu):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-PowerEdge-2850:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
```

Second use this command in shell (Ubuntu):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-PowerEdge-2850:~$ /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p database < "/opt/lampp/htdocs/database.sql"
```

Enter password: (Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Why are you importing a database.sql file and the question was specific to just starting the console?

Answer (score 1):

To start the Apache, MySQL and ProFTPD server you have to just type the following command.

```
 ~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

To open the MySQL or MariaDB console (Terminal) you have to just type the following command.

```
 ~$ sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./mysql -h localhost test
```