# Xampp: Access MySQL from terminal?

Tags: command-line, mysql, xampp

I found an answer here: [How do I start the MySQL console in XAMPP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95241/how-do-i-start-the-mysql-console-in-xampp) but it is not working for me.

First if I go to the folder

```
/opt/lampp/bin/
```

if I then call

```
mysql -u root
```

Then I get notified that this command is unknown. I don't understand why.
However, I can do

```
./mysql -u root
```

but then for some reason `MariaDB` gets started:
[image]

So whats the correct way to access MySQL from terminal?

Comment: So it starts, if so what else is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xampp uses Mariadb as drop-in replacement for MySQL. You will find Folders and file names with mysql but MariaDB is behind it. Please read [mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/)

Answer (score 9):

The reason your not able to start it `mysql -u root -p` is because the folder location `/opt/lampp/` isn't in included in your path. Add this line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin/:$PATH
```

Then close it and `source` it with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If no errors comes from the above `source` command then you can now do `mysql -u root -p` from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you start xampp by doing the following

```
   cd /opt/lampp
   sudo lampp start
```

Change to bin directory i.e

```
cd bin (if you are already in /opt/lampp) or cd /opt/lampp/bin
```

Start mariadb by typing `./mysql -u root -p`