# MySQL server is not starting in XAMPP

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, xampp

I have recently installed xampp using the following commands:

```
$ wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.20/xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
$ chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
$ sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
```

After setting up xampp the other two server are running but MySQl server is not running after starting it

[image: XAMPP]

What is the problem and how can I fix it?I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What happens when you press start while MySQL is selected? do you get any error messages?

Comment: After clicking on start it is telling starting but after few minutes it is stopping

Comment: Try to [start it from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/179228/566421): `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql` and report the error messages if there are any.

Comment: No it is not giving any error after giving the command it said XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the mysql installed in ubuntu takes over the port which will inturn block the mysql of xampp. try removing mysql completely from ubuntu and try again.
use following commands to uninstall mysql

sudo apt-get purge mysql*

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

and now start your xampp.It worked for me.